# Can't change a variable in a function if the variable is an agument

Tags: function, variables, lua, arguments

```
function bar(w)
    w = 1
end
a = 2
bar(a)
print(a) -- => 2
```

Next one is works, but it's not an argument.

```
function test()
    a = 1
end
a = 2
test(a)
print(a) -- => 1
```

How can I change a variable in function body is the variable is an argument?

Comment: This is because in Lua, you *pass by value.* What this means is that you are merely only editing **copies** of the arguments, and not the actual arguments itself. You may find this discussion useful: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-06/msg00257.html

Comment: The answers are good explanations for Lua. However, you might notice some variation in the terms "pass-by-value", "pass-by-reference", etc. They are best defined for the context they are needed and different languages have different needs. [More study.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lua most values are passed by value. Meaning when you pass them to a function, your function geys a mere copy. This includes strings, numbers, nil, and booleans. But there are 2 other datatypes (excluding userdatas).

Tables and functions.

They are pass-by-reference. What this means is, you can edit these 2 datatypes, and it will be 'permanent', because you have a reference to the original value.

Let's begin with tables. In your function if we pass a table, you can edit the properties instead:

```
function Change(x)
    x.val = 5
end

a = {val=2}
Change(a)
print(a.val)
```

Now this is trivial, so I won't be bothered to explain how it works.

Next let's use a function. But... How? How can you 'edit' a function?

Well you see, functions have these amazing things called 'upvalues'. Local values out of it's scope, so we can write a simple get/set function, like so:

```
function Change(x)
    x("set", 5)
end

do
    local val = 2
    function a(method, v)
        if method == "set" then
            val = v
        elseif method == "get" then
            return val
        end
    end
end
Change(a)
print(a("get"))
```

When you call a with set, you give the local variable outside it's scope (it's outside scope so it isn't reset every call) a new value. And get will return it.

But what if this isn't practical. Well if you want to modify global variables, you could use _G. Instead of passing the value itself, pass the variable as a string. This'll allow us to index the variable. Just as good as pass-by-reference, the downside? It won't work with locals.

```
function Change(x)
    _G[x] = 5
end

a = 2
Change('a')
print(a)
```

I hope my answer helped you!

Comment: >you could use _G;
so no way for locals?

Comment: @Parki As I mentioned in my answer, _G is useful only if you wish to change global variables. You cannot manipulate it for locals, but luckily I mentioned 2 other methods that would work locally.

Answer (score 3):

As Digital Veer indicated in the comment lua values are generally passed by value. So you can't do this.

Tables, however, are passed by reference. (See section [2.2 Values and Types](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2) in the lua manual for more discussion about this.)

So if you pass a table into the function you can modify values *inside* the table.

```
function bar(tab)
    tab.w = 1
end
local t = {w = 2}
bar(t)
print(t.w) -- => 1
```

Comment: *All* Lua values are passed by value -- table references are no exception.

Comment: @siffiejoe While true the "value" for a table is a reference to the table. Though the semantics are different enough for that to be a meaningful distinction nonetheless.